# Calling onValueChange(NumberPicker) programmatically on Android

Tags: android, listener, numberpicker

It's possible to trigger onValueChange after doing a setValue in NumberPicker?

```
valuePicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.valorDimNumberPicker);
    valuePicker.setMinValue(1);
    valuePicker.setMaxValue(10);

    valuePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            //change the world
        }
    });

 valuePicker.setValue(2);
```

After valuePicker.setValue(2), I want to execute the code under onValueChange method (change the world) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat inside `onclick()` after set `numberpicker` value the same instructions contained
in `NumberPicker` `onValueChange()`

Something like this:

```
    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.b_num_pick);
    if (np != null) {
        np.setMinValue(1);
        int maxValue =nmax;
        np.setMaxValue(maxValue);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        np.setValue(1);
        np.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                 //do something;
            }
        });
    }

    Button increment_ = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.b_increment);
    increment_ .setOnClickListener(new NumberPicker.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int oldVal,newVal;
            oldVal=np.getValue();
            newVal=oldVal+1;
            if(newVal>nmax)newVal=1;
            np.setValue(newVal);

            //do something;
        }
    });
```

For me works.

Answer (score -1):

This is a example !!!

```
    valuePicker.setMinValue(1);
    valuePicker.setMaxValue(10);
    valuePicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    valuePicker.setValue(2);

    valuePicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        //change the world
        if(newVal==3){
                picker.setValue(3);
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What I want it's to execute the onValueChange automatically every time I do a setValue() in my code, for example, when I click on a button.